# How can I force the STL memory cache to clear?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, g++

I have a class which has a field of type `unordered_map`. I create a single instance of this object in my application, which is wrapped in a `shared_ptr`. The object is very memory consuming and I want to delete it as soon as I'm done using it. However, resetting the pointer only frees a small part of the memory occupied by the object. How can I force the program to free all the memory occupied by the object?

The following mock program reproduces my problem. The for loops printing garbage are there only to give me enough time to observe the memory used with `top`. The destructor gets called just after `reset()`. Also, immediately after, the memory used drops from approx 2 GB to 1.5 GB.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  ~A() {
    cerr << "Destructor" << endl;
  }

  unordered_map<int, int> index;
};

int main() {
  shared_ptr<A> a = make_shared<A>();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 50000000; ++i) {
    a->index[2*i] = i + 3;
  }

  // Do some random work.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3000000; ++i) {
    cout << "First" << endl;
  }

  a.reset();

  // More random work.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3000000; ++i) {
    cout << "Second" << endl;
  }
}
```

Compiler: g++ 4.6.3.

Comment: [It's not called the STL.](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/)

Comment: If immediate gratification from memory disposal is what you are looking for, then use OS calls for allocating and freeing memory.  You may need to write a custom allocator and pass that to the map's constructor.

Comment: Memory used by what benchmark?

Comment: which OS? which C library?  This has nothing to do with GCC.

Comment: Have you actually been hurt by this memory usage, or is this an imagined problem?

Comment: This is _probably_ a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10943907/981959 but I'm waiting to see if it's on GNU/Linux before voting to close it. Even if it's a different OS similar principles apply.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Linux (Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC's standard library has no "STL memory cache", in its default configuration (which almost everyone uses) `std::allocator` just calls `new` and `delete`, which just call `malloc` and `free`.  The `malloc` implementation (which usually comes from the system's C library) decides whether to return memory to the OS. Unless you are on an embedded/constrained system with no virtual memory (or you've turned off over-committing) then you probably **do not want to return it** -- let the library do what it wants.

The OS doesn't need the memory back, it can allocate gigabytes of virtual memory for other applications without problems. Whenever people think they need to return memory it's usually because they don't understand how a modern OS handles virtual memory.

If you really want to force the C library to return memory to the OS, the C library might provide non-standard hooks to do so, e.g for GNU libc you can call `malloc_trim(0)` to force the top-most chunk of free memory to be returned to the OS, but that will probably make your program slower next time it needs to allocate more memory, because it will have to get it back from the OS.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10945602/981959 (and the other answers there) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

There's no guarantee that your application will free the memory back to the OS. It's still available for your application to use but the OS may not reclaim it for general use until your application exits.