# std::deque keeps consumed excess memory after frequent push and pops

Tags: c++, memory-management, windows-8, std

It took me many days and hours of efforts to narrow down on this. My application was consuming around 200 to 300 megabytes despite I was cleaning up everything. Finally I narrowed down that `std::deque` was the reason.

Code snippet below demonstrates this.

Platform: Windows 8

Compiler: Visual Studio 2012

Here am just pushing structures to `deque` and then poping them back and finally swapping it with blank deque to release memory fully (as suggested in answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242357/how-to-release-memory-from-stddeque) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834754/stddeque-does-not-release-memory-until-program-exits))

```
#include <Psapi.h>

long long GetProcessPrivateBytes() 
{
    long long privatebytes;
    HANDLE current_process;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;

    current_process = GetCurrentProcess();

    if (!GetProcessMemoryInfo(current_process, (PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS)&pmc, sizeof(pmc))) 
    {
        return -1;
    }

    privatebytes = pmc.PrivateUsage;

    return privatebytes ;
}

// Testing deque allocation
#define MYARRAY_SIZE 1024
#define MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_QUEUE (1024*1024)
struct MyStruct
{
    unsigned char MyArray[MYARRAY_SIZE];
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyStruct mystruct;

    std::queue<MyStruct> MyStructQueue;

    while(1)
    {
        int MemoryConsumedByApplication = GetProcessPrivateBytes();

        std::cout << "\n\nCurrent memory consumed by application " << (MemoryConsumedByApplication/1024)/1024 << " Megabytes";

        if (MemoryConsumedByApplication > 128*1024*1014)
        {
            std::cout << "\nApplication still consuming too much memory. Press a key to quit the loop...";
            _getch();
            break;
        }

        std::cout << "\nFiling up queue with " << MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_QUEUE << " structs each of size " <<  MYARRAY_SIZE;
        for (int i=0; i<MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_QUEUE; i++)
        {
            MyStructQueue.push(mystruct);
        }

        std::cout << "\nQueue filled up. Now poping back all elements...";
        for (int i=0; i<MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_QUEUE; i++)
        {
            MyStructQueue.pop();
        }

        std::cout << "\nQueue poped back (Size " << MyStructQueue.size() << "). Now swaping with blank queue.";

        std::queue<MyStruct>().swap(MyStructQueue);
    }
    std::cout << "\nPress a key to exit...";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

> ```
> Current memory consumed by application 0 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 5 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 5 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 6 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 5 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 6 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 6 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 6 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 6 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 6 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 6 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 7 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 7 Megabytes
> Filing up queue with 1048576 structs each of size 1024
> Queue filled up. Now poping back all elements...
> Queue poped back (Size 0). Now swaping with blank queue.
>
> Current memory consumed by application 198 Megabytes
> Application still consuming too much memory. Press a key to quit the loop...
> ```

Thus, it can be seen that after few iterations application holds bulk amount of memory and since there is nothing other than `std::deque` in the code, this memory must have been consumed by the `std::deque`.

Any idea why this happens and how to make application completely free of any allocation?

Comment: It's certainly not the STL, read the tag wiki please, before using this tag or term.

Comment: Tag wiki gives general description of stl. This question is related to one of stl containers hence I added the tag. Other two questions (which I've referred in this question) on similar issue also have stl tagged in them.

Comment: Read it again, it's the old specific hp implementation. You are talking about the c++ standard library, we have 2015 now dude.

Comment: Omg, now I realized wht you were trying to suggest. I've made appropriate changes. I hope now it's in the order.

Comment: Does one additional iteration through the `while` loop make memory consumption jump suddenly from 7 MB to 198 MB as your output indicates? Or did you strip a lot of the output when you pasted it in your question?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (linux gcc 5.1), are you sure your `GetProcessPrivateBytes()` isn't providing spurious results?

Comment: @WhiteViking: Nope I didn't stripped off any output line. It sudenly jumps from 7 MB to 198 MB in exact same iterations.

Comment: @Galik: It's in Windows 8. I verified through task manager it reports same amout of memory.

Comment: The answer to this question seems to lie in the exact meaning of `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX.PrivateUsage` and deeper understanding of low-level Windows memory handling. Not in `std::deque` itself.